# ValueError: Symbol table not found

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to install scikit-learn; following the [instructions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html), I downloaded the source and attempted to install it with `python setup.py install`, however the installation is interrupted at:

```
 File "C:\Users\Alpine\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompi
ler.py", line 278, in generate_def
    raise ValueError("Symbol table not found")
ValueError: Symbol table not found
```

I've also tried using `easy_install -U scikit-learn`, although end up with the same error.

Using `conda install scikit-learn` appeared to install the conda-3.4.1-py27_0.tar.bz2 and numpy-1.8.1-py27_0.tar.bz2 packages, and for safe measure I ran `conda update anaconda`, although I'm still receiving the same error.

Would anybody know how to work around this?

Comment: `conda install scikit-learn` should work (unless you need to be on the latest development version of course)

Comment: @Matt I gave it a shot and the packages seemed to have installed successfully, although I'm still receiving the same error. Might you happen to know why?

Comment: Is reinstalling anaconda in its default location an option? (e.g. `c:\Anaconda`). Are you running your commands from a `cygwin` terminal (if so, try running `conda ...` in a regular command line`)

Comment: Looking at the source code of `numpy` this seems to be related to some kind of library error (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py#L268)

Comment: @Matt I've just tried (re)installing Anaconda to `c:\Anaconda`, though when I try running `conda` in the command line I get `'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command...`, so I may have to (re)install it in my own user directory (rather than the C: drive); I've been running the commands in the regular command terminal.

Comment: That's strange. The `conda` script is usually located under `C:\Anaconda\Scripts` and is added automatically to the `PATH` variable during the installation. Can you check if that this directory is in your `PATH` variable?

Comment: @Matt Yes, changing the %PATH% allowed for `conda install scikit-learn` to run without interruption. Oddly enough when I attempt to run `python setup.py install`, I'm getting **ValueError: [u'path']**, though that of course is a different error.

Answer (score 0):

This  solution  will  take  care  of "symbol table not found" error  from  numpy (or any other package ) on windows machine

sklearn people  have  provided  good  solution  for  this  over here

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#building-on-windows

you can  find  instruction  for  Linux  and  mac  on  same  page

now  just  follow these  steps

32-bit Python

For 32-bit python it is possible use the standalone installers for microsoft visual c++ express 2008 for Python 2 or Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010 for Python 3.
Once installed you should be able to build scikit-learn without any particular configuration by running the following command in the scikit-learn folder:
python setup.py install
64-bit Python

For the 64-bit architecture, you either need the full Visual Studio or the free Windows SDKs that can be downloaded from the links below.

The Windows SDKs include the MSVC compilers both for 32 and 64-bit architectures. They come as a GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso file that can be mounted as a new drive with a setup.exe installer in it.

**For Python 2 you need SDK v7.0: MS Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 -> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18950

For Python 3 you need SDK v7.1: MS Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4** -> (can't  post  link  as  i  need  atleast 10  reputation point )
Both SDKs can be installed in parallel on the same host. To use the Windows SDKs, you need to setup the environment of a cmd console launched with the following flags (at least for SDK v7.0):

**cmd /E:ON /V:ON /K**
Then configure the build environment with:

**SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
SET MSSdk=1
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Setup\WindowsSdkVer.exe" -q -version:v7.0
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64 /release**

after typing  above  commands in cmd as soon as you  hit  enter  the window  will be  changed  lil  bit ( font color changed to  green ) now  go to  directory  where you  have  downloaded sklearn zip file  from git hub  then un-zip it
   and go  to  directory where you can  find  setup.py
run command

python setup.py install

if  it's not  recognizing  python then you  migh  have  missed  this  command
**cmd /E:ON /V:ON /K**

so  till  now  if  u  have  done  everything  correct then  your  package  will  be  installed  without  any  difficulties